# GetSysColorBrush constant for background color of a tab control?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, common-controls

I'm using the following APIs to draw a small stock icon on the background of my [tab control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760550(v=vs.85).aspx) window (with class name `SysTabControl32`):

```
DrawIconEx(hDC, rcIcon.left, rcIcon.top,
    hIconSmInfo, rcIcon.Width(), rcIcon.Height(), NULL, 
    ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW),
    DI_NORMAL);
```

But it doesn't seem to draw consistent background. Let me show.

On a themed Windows 7:

[image]

It draws it correctly:

[image]

But if I remove themes:

[image]

It draws this white background:

[image]

So what constant do I need to use for `GetSysColorBrush`?

Comment: The introduction of themes was evil on Microsoft's part, because now you need two different code paths in far too many places. I doubt there's a single constant you can use that works in both cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Thanks. So I need to define if themes are enabled, right? Any recommended steps?

Comment: I'd start by calling [`IsThemeActive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759813(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: DrawIconEx can draw icons transparently, why do you need a background color at all?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Oh, wow. That's embarrassing. All I needed to do was to specify `NULL` for the 8th parameter in `DrawIconEx`. Oops. Thanks.